# How to save then retrieve image with specific name in Photo album?

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried following ways but that does not save image with given names.

**First Attempt**: Successful but does not save with given name

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
var dir = paths[0] as! String
var filePath = "\\(dir)/imageName.jpg"
var saveImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(saveImage, self, nil, nil)
```

**2nd Attempt**: Failed to save image

```
var data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
data.writeToFile(filePath, true)
```

Finally I had saved my Image to NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory with specific name. Even when it is not visible, we can search file with specific name and open/show in UIImageView.
As far as best of my knowledge, iPhone does not allow you to write or search by name Image to Photo gallery, programmatically. If we can, please tell me how.

Answer (score 3):

Before you use this, its my advice that you **please go through the photos framework of iOS**.

Create a singleton class for the same -

```
class CreateCustomPhotoAlbum: NSObject
    {
        static let albumName = "Your album name"
        static let sharedInstance = createCustomPhotoAlbum()

        var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!

        override init() {
            super.init()

            if let assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum()
            {
                self.assetCollection = assetCollection
                return
            }

            if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized
            {
                PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) -> Void in
                    status
                })
            }

            if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
                self.createAlbum()
            } else {
                PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(requestAuthorizationHandler)
            }
        }

        func requestAuthorizationHandler(status: PHAuthorizationStatus)
        {
            if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized {
                // ideally this ensures the creation of the photo album even if authorization wasn't prompted till after init was done
                print("trying again to create the album")
                self.createAlbum()
            } else {
                print("should really prompt the user to let them know it's failed")
            }
        }

        func createAlbum() {
            PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle(createCustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)   // create an asset collection with the album name
                }) { success, error in
                    if success {
                        self.assetCollection = self.fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum()
                    } else {
                        print("error \(error)")
                    }
            }
        }

        func fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() -> PHAssetCollection!
        {
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", createCustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)
            let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Album, subtype: .Any, options: fetchOptions)

            if let _: AnyObject = collection.firstObject {
                return collection.firstObject as! PHAssetCollection
            }
            return nil
        }

        func saveImage(image: UIImage)
        {
            if assetCollection == nil
            {
                return                          // if there was an error upstream, skip the save
            }

            PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
                let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(image)
                let assetPlaceHolder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(forAssetCollection: self.assetCollection)
                albumChangeRequest!.addAssets([assetPlaceHolder!])
                }, completionHandler: nil)
        }

    }
```

**Save Image**

Just simply call this -

```
createCustomPhotoAlbum.sharedInstance.saveImage(imageName!)
```

Comment: Great code but this is not saving the first image, any idea why?